# Why are US treasury bonds priced in 32nds?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

What is the historical reason for treasury bonds to be priced in 32nds?

I have tried using Google and this site to find the answer, but have not been able to find anything definite.

Three possibilities I found during my search that had no documentation what so ever backing them up:

1. Probably a carry-over from European influence in monetary system.  Spain had "pieces of 8" coins... bonds might have been tic-priced on that concept... "1/8" of something being the smallest denomination.  For bonds 1/8 was too large of a tic?  So, 1/32 = 1/4 of 1/8. [source](http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/printthread.php?threadid=217026)
2. I believe it’s because the old ticker machines only had 32 symbols making each symbol (1/32) a tick. [source](http://www.analystforum.com/forums/cfa-forums/cfa-level-ii-forum/91307064)
3. I suppose it remains from the LSD days when an eighth of a pound was 2s6d

Just something I always wondered about, but never actually got anyone to answer.  So I hope someone on here knows why!

Comment: Which country's treasury bonds are you referring to? Got links for your quoted sources?

Comment: added sources and country in question. also, i cant add the third source link, because lack of points. It came from here: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100412125628AADHTyS

Comment: "pieces of eight! pieces of eight!" where each piece (bit) of a dollar was 12.5 cents.  Two bits made a quarter.  Two shillings and six pence was usually referred to as a _half-crown_ in the old British currency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It used to be that stocks were traded in fractions too. It was only recently that they all were converted over into [decimals](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/decimalization.asp).

I think you're basically right about being a holdover [from Europe, especially Spain](http://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/financial-planning/stock-market-use-fractions.htm):

> These early stockbrokers [who were trying to create the NYSE] looked to 
>   Europe for a model to build their
>   system on and decided to base it on the system of Spain. This was
>   largely due to the fact that the U.S. dollar's value had been based on
>   the value of the Spanish real.
>
> The real was the Spanish silver dollar and was divided into eight
>   parts. This evolved from the method of counting on the hands, similar
>   to the decimal system. The difference was that the decimal system used
>   the thumbs as part of the number while this other system used the
>   thumbs to denote the total of the four fingers. Therefore, a person
>   would count to four on one hand and then use the thumb to indicate a
>   total while they counted on the other hand. Two thumbs equaled eight.
>   The real could be broken into two, four or eight parts, giving birth
>   to the term pieces of eight.

Comment: great, thanks mlathe! Do you know of any sources to back this story up historically?

Comment: Except for the "how stuff works" [link](http://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/financial-planning/stock-market-use-fractions.htm) I gave from above, no not really. I looked a bit more, and found a few more "sources", but i wouldn't call them authoritative: [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/04/073004.asp), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dollar#United_States) (last paragraph of US section)

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification. because this is the only answer so far, i have chosen it as the accepted answer.